# Why is the boolean undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined, undefined-reference

In javascript I do:

```
var myObject = {
  myBoo: false,
  myMethod: function () {
     console.log("my method: "+ myBoo);
  }
}
console.log("myObject.myBoo=" + myObject.myBoo);
myObject.myMethod();
```

This outputs:

```
myObject.myBoo=false
ReferenceError: myBoo is not defined
```

Why is myBoo undefeind from myMethod's perspective?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because myBoo is not defined as a global variable, but rather as an object property. The proper way of accessing it in the `myMethod` function would therefore be:

```
console.log("my method: "+ this.myBoo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **this** to refer to the object:

```
myMethod: function () {
    console.log("my method: "+ this.myBoo);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xB83/

Here's a great article about **this** http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Answer (score 1):

myBoo is an attribute of the object hence you will have to access it in reference to the object itself.

it should be this.myBoo in the myMethod function()

Answer (score 1):

Your function "myMethod" is trying to access local variable myBoo which *doesn't exist* in the context of your function!  What you meant to do is use this.myBoo.